# Datetime type compared with Date type

Tags: sql, date, datetime, comparison

I have a project where I am comparing a value of datetime type to a value of straight date.  For example the following:
 '2014-01-01 06:05:00' >= '2014-01-01' or '2014-01-01 06:05:00' <= '2014-01-01'

Do I need to worry about this comparison not returning a correct answer under some situations that I am not aware of?  My program says it will be changing the date type to a datetime type.

Comment: ***What*** RDBMS is this about ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to see if a timestamp falls on a particular day, you should perform either:

- an equality test of the truncated timestamp (time portion removed) against the date or
- a pair of tests where the timestamp is greater than or equal to the date provided and less than said date plus one day, *i.e.*, midnight the following day.